# How do I download Hibernate 6.4.4 JARs?

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, import, jar

While following Hibernate tutorials on Youtube, they all include a step where they download Hibernate JAR files from the official website, but when I visited the latest version page (Hibernate 6.4.4) there was no download option? So how can I download them please? I am doing a simple JAVA project that have no POM file so I need the JARs to be added to Eclipse in order to be able to integrate it

Comment: Poor tutorials... you should use maven or gradle to manage dependencies instead of manually downloading them.

Answer (score 1):

### Manual download

If you insist on manually downloading the library, navigate from the [*Releases*](https://hibernate.org/orm/releases/) page to find a download link.

Look for *Direct download* section with links to specific instructions for manual download.

### Dependency manager

Libraries used by your app (“dependencies”) are commonly downloaded and installed automatically by using a dependency management tool. The most popular such tools nowadays are [*Apache Maven*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) and [*Apache Gradle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle), with others competing as well.

You simply tell the dependency manager what libraries you want, by listing them in a configuration file. Maven uses XML file (a POM) while Gradle uses a [Groovy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groovy_(programming_language)) file.

All common IDEs (IntelliJ, Eclipse, NetBeans, etc.) nowadays are savvy with using both Maven and Gradle.

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>6.4.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```